# Is there an algorithm to add edges to a DAG to make it strongly connected with minimum cost?

Tags: graphs

I have a weighted DAG and a function computing the weight of edges that is not connected in the DAG. The weight of `u` to `v` equals to the weight of `v` to `u`.

I want to connect edges to make the DAG a single strongly connected component (any vertex in the new graph can reach any other vertex) with minimum total weights of added edges.

I know that the minimum number of added edges equals to $\text{max}(|source|, |sink|)$ but which vertex connects to which vertex so that the total weights is minimum?

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? Any algorithm? The complexity class of the problem? Approximation results?

Comment: Can you add a url to the original problem?

Comment: My problem is similar to this problem https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/15102. In my problem, the graph needed to be modified is a DAG because I collapased each SCC into a vertex.